# How to keep loading status in async react-select if toggle select component when loading

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I need to use asyncSelect component of react-select to load async data but encountered a problem. When I init the component, the loading bubbles and fetch data request both work well, but during loading progress, if I click the component to toggle the option panel and then click somewhere else to hide the panel again, the loading bubbles will disappear and the 'loading' label will be changed to 'no options'. All of these looks like the request has completed and get none option. Actually at this time the request is still on process.

The react-select version: 3.0.2

I just make official example longger time interval and the code is as below.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-2rzdw

I know that I can set a state to disable which means when the request is still on process, I can make the component disabled so that users cannot click the component. But the disabled select component has different color and some other styles which will break the consistency of my page. So what I expect is that the bubbles and 'loading' label can show all the time util the request finishes, no matter I do what kind of operations.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. If you try to control to `isLoading` prop and set it to `true` all the time, the loading disappears when the panel mount/unmount. I suggest you use [downshift](https://github.com/downshift-js/downshift) for flexibility.